# Creating surface layer from Points in ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, 3d-analyst, arcscene, surface

I work in ArcScene where i have some buildings in 3D, on the facades of these buildings in have points of solar intensity. I would like to create a continuous surface of solar intensity for each facade. I tried Interpolation with kriging but doesn't seem to work,

Does anyone have an idea how can i achieve this?

I join a picture for a better understanding.

[image]